# tools::texi2dvi - what happened to it?

Tags: r, latex, package, cran

I'm familiar with the fact that you can create LaTeX reports directly from R with `tools` package and `texi2dvi` function, but I was surprised to see that `tools` package is missing. It's just not in CRAN repositories. Does anyone know about an adequate replacement for `texi2dvi`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `tools` package is part of R itself.  CRAN has recommended packages, but not the core packages shipped with the sources.

See e.g. [here in the sources themselves](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/) for the list of included packages.

Comment: Oh, boy... now, this was embarrassing... Thanks Dirk! I'd like to state that temperature in my town reaches 38 C, if that's an appropriate excuse! =) I should have put `tools::texi2dvi - what happened to me` O_o